# (Cosmos) This line of code won't work: [assembly: Rings(System.Rings)]

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, hal, cosmos

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Cosmos.HAL;
using Sys = Cosmos.System;
using Cosmos.Common;
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Package Name")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Company")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Package Name")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
[assembly: CLSCompliant(false)]
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US")]
[assembly: Rings(System.Rings)]
```

Why does this not work? It should work going by tutorials. The error is that Rings is not recognized.